# URLs rewritten from MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK

Tags: azure, http, url, networking

We have a website which cart accepts URL with parameters from newsletters or online offers. The URL is like the following:

```
ourwebsite.com/cart/?c=INTEGER&product=INTEGER&coupon=SOMEVOUCHER
```

Let's narrow it down to something like.

```
ourwebsite.com/cart/?c=1&product=3&coupon=AAAAAA
```

We have detected that when the HTTP requests come from some network block with ISP ID: **MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK**, which seems to be coming from MS Azure, the coupon parameter is changed to:

```
ourwebsite.com/cart/?c=1&product=3&coupon=BBBBBB
```

The coupon code is of the same length as the original, but it obviously makes our cart page return an `"Invalid coupon"` message resulting in the client leaving the page.

Can anybody shed some light on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be Safe-Links feature in MS products

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/safe-links

In our case this "feature" is selectively rewriting only some parts in our -add to cart- URLs, in a way that messes them up completely.

I won't judge on the kind of "features" that MS adds to their products, each one should draw his own conclusions.

Comment: Facing a similar issue here. Have you found a way to mitigate this? Do the URLs remain messed up when the user clicks on them or are they only randomized when safe-links checks the URL?

Comment: This is just MS like behaviour, they try to destroy to then own the remains.